# Linking images in InDesign

Tags: images, adobe-cs5, adobe-indesign

I have InDesign files with linked images. When I open the file, it says none of the files are linked. So I go in and link all the files correctly and save it. But when I close the file and reopen it, the images are once again unlinked.

How do I keep the files linked?

Comment: If you move any of the images that the InDesign file has linked to it will ask you to relink them. You can either stop moving images around or you can try embedding the images in the InDesign file (which will make a huge file size and isn't always a great idea).

Answer (score 1):

Avoid renaming the image files or any of the folders that have to be opened  to get to them.

It also helps if all images are stored in the same folder. Relinking one file (if this ever happens again) will give you a one-click prompt to update all missing files.